# Guava. CharStreams check for null

Tags: java, guava

Can I check the streams value for null by this exception:

(null != supplier)

Or i need check:

(null != readerSupplier.getInput())

Should I flush() output stream?
See comments.

public void run() {

```
    try {
        final Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        InputSupplier<InputStreamReader> readerSupplier = CharStreams.newReaderSupplier(new InputSupplier<InputStream>() {
            @Override
            public InputStream getInput() throws IOException {
                return process.getInputStream();
            }
        }, Charsets.UTF_8);
        OutputSupplier<OutputStreamWriter> writerSupplier = CharStreams.newWriterSupplier(new OutputSupplier<OutputStream>() {
            @Override
            public OutputStream getOutput() throws IOException {
                return process.getOutputStream();
            }
        }, Charsets.UTF_8);
        // can I check the stream objects for null readerSupplier/writerSupplier?
        // or need: readerSupplier.getInput()/writerSupplier.getOutput()?
        if (null != readerSupplier && null != writerSupplier) {
            ...
            CharStreams.write(someCommand, writerSupplier);
            // should I flush() output stream? How better? Flushables.flush(writerSupplier) or Flushables.flush(writerSupplier.getOutput())  
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Javadoc of `Process`, it doesn't look like any of these values could ever be null, so you shouldn't need to check any of the values for null, full stop.

In any event, the purpose of using `OutputSupplier` in `CharStreams.write` is that it will open, write, and close the stream without you having to do anything, so there's no need to `flush` or do anything at all.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Very useful class. Another question: Is it appropriate to use the facilities "Supplier" platform "Android"? Would not it be performance issues?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be any performance issues with the `Supplier` types on Android.

Comment: I will say that I wouldn't necessarily recommend using `Input/OutputSupplier` for this. They are generally expected to be usable more than once to return a new, independent stream each time. Since a `Process` just has one of each stream and returns that same stream each time `getInputStream()`, etc. is called, you'll have a problem if you try to use the supplier more than once since the stream will have been closed.